# How to perform update slots from 2 sql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing a booking cancellation function. I have successfully removed the data in reservation table as shown in the code below. However, I would like to update the status for the timeslots. For the timeslots table, 1 = not available for booking anymore, 0 = available for booking. While the user logs in into the account, they can view the appointment and perform booking cancellation, which is where I am stuck with on updating the timeslots to make it available for booking again.

For the reservations table, its status means visited or not visited, which is not related to this question. However, the reservation table is the table which shows the information to the users to view their appointment history, and here is where the cancellation feature will be provided, using a button.

The problem is that I do not know how to connect between the reservation table and the timeslot table. I need the timeslot table to show the updated status is 0 after cancellation happens for a particular day instead of continue showing 1. Below I will attach the database in SQL and the codes implemented.

Timeslots database:
[image: timeslots table]

Reservations database:
[image: reservations table]

```
    public function destroy($id,Request $request){
        //delete reservation in records
        $reservation = Reservation::find($id);
        $reservationDelete = $reservation->delete();      

        //how to update the timeslots status to become 0 from timeslots database?
        return redirect()->route('my.appointment')->with('message', 'Appointment has been cancelled successfully');

    }
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use MySQL transaction to do this both modification in 1 transaction.

I recommend to use 2 different query in 1 transaction.

Your description about this problem is not fully clear, sorry for misunderstand.

Comment: Hi there! thanks for your reply..I have updated the description..Please help :) thank you again.